# Word that denotes the belief that women are inferior to men

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that denotes the belief that women are or should be inferior to men? For example,

> That ideology advocates murder, rape, slavery, homophobia, xenophobia and [insert the requested word here].

The word *patriarchy* comes to mind but I am not sure if it fits in the sentence above. I am also thinking of *sexism*, but it denotes prejudice based on sex, which, although in practice usually against women, can work both ways.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Patriarchy* would not fit because the other words in the list show that you are searching for the negative meaning, while *patriarchy* would be too neutral or even positive to fit in the list. But you already got good answers in the mean time.

Comment: On the other hand..."I married beneath me. All women do." - Lady Astor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Misogyny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogyny)?

Comment: That's not so much a *belief* as an irrational obsession, though.

Comment: I was going to suggest _misogyny_ but OP's op didn't seem to call for outright hatred of women.

Comment: @cornbreadninja: Well, the wiki link says that it's not only hatred but also discrimination etc., so I think it fits. Don't you?

Comment: I put a question-mark by my suggestion for a reason. It might work, depending on the context. @Daniel: "_the belief that women are or should be inferior to men_..." - I'd call that an irrational belief.

Comment: J.R. True - both male chauvisnism and misogyny are very irrational.  I'm still trying to think of a good way to state the difference.  @cornbread ninja hit on something there.  I think the main difference is that male chauvinism isn't as individual.  Imagine one of the eras where male chauvinism reigned; it isn't necessarily the case that each individual hated women, merely that they were brought up to think that they were in every way inferior to men.  So there could be (and have been) people who don't hate women, but simply believe that they are inferior.  Misogyny is a case-by-case problem

Comment: What I meant by irrational was that no one has to teach misogyny; it's not a tradition.  It's acquired without reason.  Male chauvinism, on the other hand, is generally taught and handed down by tradition.

Comment: I think the distinction here is that misogyny is rooted in hatred which can lead to discrimination etc.  While male chauvinism reflects a simple feeling of superiority as in, "we don't hate them, they're simply just not as good."

Comment: @Jim: precisely, which is why I recommended _misogyny_.  _Misogyny_ is by no means a nice word - which is why it fits with _murder, rape, slavery, homophobia, and xenophobia,_ (which aren't very nice words, either).

Comment: Ok, after re-reading the OP's question it appears to me to be inconsistent. The first sentence only asks about inferiority (for which male chauvinism fits) but that is _*completely*_ different than the example he gives (for which misogyny fits).

Comment: @Jim: The first sentence doesn't "only" ask about inferiority, it asks about "**the belief that women are or should be inferior to men.**"  I find that to be a misogynist world view.  The belief that women _are_ inferior is chauvinism; the belief that women _should be_ inferior is misogyny.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան There is also a much less common opposite word "misandry," which means a belief that men are inferior to women.

Answer (score 9):

[Male chauvinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism) is the term I've heard for this:

> *Male chauvinism* is a term used to describe the belief that men are superior to women. It is often used interchangeably with "sexism" and is closely associated with misogyny and perceptions of women as inferior to men, especially intellectually. The unqualified term "chauvinism" is far more likely to refer to a male chauvinism than female chauvinism in the context of chauvinism as sexism.

Comment: Note that "chauvinism" can refer to any claim of arbitrary superiority. It was originally used in reference to the extreme (French) nationalism of Nicholas Chauvin, and for a time was understood to mean something like "extreme patriotism". It is occasionally used in other contexts today, but admittedly is now mostly used in the phrase "male chauvinism".

Comment: @Jay, agreed, I think the 'male' is necessary to make the 'chauvinism' more specific.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [androcentrism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/androcentrism?s=t).

> centered on, emphasizing, or dominated by males or masculine interests: *an androcentric society*; *an androcentric religion*.

Comment: A bit obscure, but probably best captures what the OP intended.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I think _androcentric_ can be used in a **neutral** way, without implying anything negative about women, or discriminating against the opposite sex. Obstetrics may be a gynocentric field, but that doesn't imply any kind of animosity toward men. Fraternities are androcentric; sororities are gynocentric. (BTW, Mark, just to clarify: it was **not** my downvote).

Comment: @J.R.: I agree (it wasn't my downvote either), I think the OP wanted neutral and this is probably as neutral as they come. While some might find the meaning relatively easy to understand the first time they see it, it's not a very common word and might confuse many, especially non-native English speakers.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Given that he was looking for a word to go at the end of "rape, slavery, homophobia, xenophobia, and `_______`," I didn't assume he was looking for a neutral word - in fact, I assumed the opposite. That said, _androcentrism_ is indeed one fine neutral word, in case my assumption was erroneous.